# Make index.cgi redirect to Apache webserver document root

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, cgi

I'm trying to expose a CGI file as my document root and web server. I do not want to expose the fact that the server is running a CGI script.

How can I map a URL `http://host/index.cgi/` back to `http://host/` in Apache2? I'm guessing it involves mod-rewrite, but I haven't finished grokking all the docs yet.

The following configuration is working, but I'm guessing there is a more complete solution:

```
RewriteEngine ON
Redirect /index.cgi/    /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct solution using mod-rewrite.

- Update CGI script to rewrite URLs to desired path. This means that URLS like `index.cgi/path` change to `/app1/path` or in my case, just `/path`. For my script there was an option called `virutal-root` that made a global change.
- Then udpate Apache with the following directives. What it does, is internally rewrite all the URLs to include the CGI script, but ignore URLs going to the actual script.

  ```
  RewriteEngine ON
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    !^/index.cgi
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$            /index.cgi/$1   [PT]
  ```
- One sticking point, is that if the CGI script references any static files on the server, they need to be placed in a path that is also out of the rewrite rule. So for example, exclude another path, before the RewriteRule:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{REQUST_URI}     !^/_static
  ```

Answer (score 1):

> but I'm guessing there is a more complete solution:

If you want to redirect requests for `/index.cgi/` to `/`, then there's really no need for anything else. Note that `RewriteEngine On` is part of mod_rewrite, and the `Redirect` directive is part of mod_alias. You don't need the rewrite engine for the redirect to work. Also note that this is a 302 redirect, and it isn't a permanent one. You probably want to include either the `301` or `permanent` keywords in there:

```
Redirect 301 /index.cgi/ /
```

Additionally, the `Redirect` directive links two path nodes together, so any further paths appended to the source gets appended to the destination. So given the above, if you go to:

```
http://host/index.cgi/some/more/path.txt
```

The browser will get redirected to:

```
http://host/some/more/path.txt
```

If you don't want this, you can change the `Redirect` to a `RedirectMatch` and use a regular expression:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.cgi/$ /
```

Comment: Do know how you can hide the index.cgi in the URL, but have the path values passed to the script? Using the first Redirect breaks the script after the main page.